# PyQt6/PySide6: how to set QFrame size by content?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I have created a `QFrame` where I put 2 `QPushButtons`.

I inserted this `QFrame` into the main `QVBoxLayout` along with the main widget (the main widget is also a `QFrame`).

The `main widget` is much larger in height, because of this my `QFrame` with two buttons sets the height of the main widget.

Is it possible to set the size of a `QFrame` so that it is equal to the size of the contents of this `QFrame`?

Part of code (`QFrame` with buttons):

```
# buttons
self.buttons_layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.buttons_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
self.buttons_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.btn1 = QPushButton("1")
self.btn2 = QPushButton("2")
self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.btn2)

self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pages_layout.setCurrentIndex(0))
self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pages_layout.setCurrentIndex(1))

self.buttons_widget = QFrame()
self.buttons_widget.setObjectName("buttons_frame")
self.buttons_widget.setStyleSheet(f"#buttons_frame{{margin-top: {self.bar.height()+6}px;}}")
self.buttons_widget.setLayout(self.buttons_layout)
```

Result:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: Put the frame inside a container widget with a vertical layout, and add an expanding spacer below the frame (i.e. `layout.addStretch()`). Or, even better, use a grid-layout for all the widgets, so you don't have to abuse stylesheets to hack the margins.